# Chat en android, sin servidor intermediario

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero hacer un **chat en android**, donde los mensajes del chat pasen **directamente** entre teléfono y teléfono, sin necesidad de pasar por el servidor. El proceso para iniciar un chat entre un usuario A y B sería algo así:

1. El usuario A se conecta al servidor.
2. Busca al usuario B en la BD del servidor.
3. A partir de haberlo encontrado, el usuario A inicia una conexión con el usuario B.
4. Los mensajes se envían entre los teléfonos sin pasar por el servidor.

¿Es posible no depender de un servidor para enviar los mensajes a los clientes? Si es así, ¿alguna idea para realizar este proceso?

Comment: Podrías probar UDP Multicast o revisar la palabra clave STUN server.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es sobre programación.

Comment: o.o Como que no es sobre programación? xD

Comment: Bueno, gracias por las respuestas. Me pondré a ello :)

Comment: @EmanuelVe si tuvieras razón, con lo que dices, como crees que funcionan skype o telefonos SIP en celulares? A ti tambien recomienda leer sobre el protocolo STUN (RFC 5389)

Comment: no quieres un servidor intermedio, pero mencionas un servidor, es confuso

Comment: No lo quiero para los mensajes que se envían, pero una BD de usaurios es necesaria..

Comment: Lo es, @FelixBeeb, no por la pregunta pero por el problema del NAT. Para comunicación p2p sobre NAT si se necesita un servidor, pero no para la conexión entera, peros para iniciar una conexión que traspasa el NAT.

Comment: comprendo lo del NAT, pero la falta de un servidor que gestione los mensajes es un problema grande, has pensado en la perdida de datos, piensa en si sera por UDP o no, son varios factores a considerar ... para que deseas evitar el servidor?

Comment: Otra posibilidad podría ser el programarlo usando el Bluetooh En caso de que aplique. Aunque estaría limitado por la distancia de 10 a 15 Metros. Por otro lado hay un proyecto llamado "Serval" que es un software libre que permite crear redes locales entre smartphones sin perjuicio de las demás redes la url es http://www.servalproject.org/ puede mirar mas información en http://blogthinkbig.com/smartphones-conectados-en-red/

Comment: @FelixBeeb hay casos de uso útiles, por ejemplo si quieres enviar contenido multimedia entre los clientes. Se ahorra mucho trafico evitando que todos estos datos se transfieren vía un servidor. Sin embargo es necesario tomando en cuenta que prácticamente todos los dispositivos móviles se encuentran tras de un NAT de usar un servidor para negociar la conexión, sea con SIP, STUN o RTMFP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible, pero sería bueno de concretar un poco tu caso de uso.

Las ideas son:

- Usa un servidor STUN (RFC 5389) par permitir una conexión p2p con NAT entremedio
- Implementa el chat usando RTMFP (RFC 7016)
- Considera UDP, negociando IP y puerto con un servidor central
- En caso de chat entre grupos, considera UDP Multicast

Comment: Buen aporte! un paradigma muy interesante.

Comment: he borrado el comentario porque confunde y no suma nada. gracias por tomarte la molestia de enseñarme XD

Comment: No hay de que, yo también a veces no encuentro mis llaves XD

Comment: No sera mejor una conexión TCP en vez que UPD ? Para evitar la perdida de datos

Comment: Si usas TCP perdida de datos se evita en capa 4, en UDP en capa 5. Tienes que implementar un _ack_ propio. El problema con TCP es obtener la conexión en primer lugar sobre NAT, eso es más facil en UDP.